# Finding the area between two regions in the plane

Tags: calculus, area

I have two regions, given by $y>\sqrt{2}x - \frac{1}{4x}$ and $y< \sqrt{2}x + \frac{1}{4x}$. How can I find the area of their intersection? If their is no easy analytical way, could someone perhaps use a computer? I am not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

[image: The searched ara is the dark blue one]

We can notice that the searched area is:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \sqrt{2}x+\frac{1}{4x}-(\sqrt{2}x-\frac{1}{4x})=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}=\infty$$

:)

Comment: See the thing going off to the right? Is there any way to prove that there are only finitely many elements of the integer lattice contained in that area as you go to infinity?